# CPU and its operations

Tags: memory, cpu, io, computer-architecture

The 3 operations performed by a CPU are:

- Transfer of data between memory and I/O
- Logical and Arithmetical functions
- Program flow through simple decisions

I dont understand what the 3rd operation is exactly

Comment: Modern cpu's do a whole lot more than that.

Comment: @Well my book says what I have written

Comment: @MissMulan - It seems you are a student. You really should be using your professor as a resource if you are confused by the material.  While we can given you an accurate description off what a CPU does, if you go beyond the course work your professor has provided, your professor might not appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Program flow through simple decisions" are instructions similar to "if value in register X is greater than Y then jump to memory location Z"

These are what is known as Flow Control Logic and include things such as [Jump if Greater or Equal](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Jump_if_Greater_or_Equal). Basically it looks at the result of the previous instruction and if that value is larger than the value presented then it will move the current code execution pointer (the "program counter") in the CPU to a location specified and continue execution from that point. The CPU will then fetch instructions from that location, and then execute them.

There are many other related instructions that fit in the group of flow control logic.